# SQL trigger to limit the number of users

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, limit

I'm still learning how to use SQL, and I need some help creating this database.

I've created the following tables:

```
create table Worker
(Num_Worker number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar2(30),
ID number(8),
Password varchar2(20));

create table Area
(Code_Area number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar2(30),
Current_workers number(2)
Max_workers number(2));

create table Timetable
(ID_Timetable number(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
Time_Entrance date,
Time_Exit date,
Code_Area number(10),
Num_Worker number(20),
Foreign Key (Num_Worker) references Worker(Num_Worker),
Foreign Key (Code_Area) references Area(Code_Area));
```

Supposedly, each worker can choose a area to work at, but each area has a limit or workers at the same time.

What would happen is a worker would create a new timetable, but before that timetable is created it should check the area that he chose to check if the "Current_workers" is the same value as "Max_workers", and if it is it shouldn't let it happen.

I've been trying to create a trigger for that, but I've had no luck in finding the correct syntax for it, and I'm not sure how to do it either, or if there's a better way to do it than with a trigger.
This is all I've done so far:

```
create trigger limit_worker_per_zone
before insert
on Timetable
for each row
as
 BEGIN
  if (select Current_Workers from Area) >= (select Max_workers from Area) <-Not sure...
  BEGIN
    ???
  END
 END
```

I'd really appreciate if you can help me in this.  I'll still be looking for more info myself meanwhile, but the more help the better.

Comment: It is always a good idea to state the database that you are using.

Comment: What @Gordon means is are you using MySql, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres etc.

Comment: Or, to put it more bluntly, your question is just gibberish as long as you don't name the RDBMS (and version) you are working with. It's not PostgreSQL, I can tell from `varchar2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER limit_worker_per_zone
BEFORE INSERT
ON Timetable
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 v_total NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   BEGIN 
    SELECT max_workers - current_workers
    INTO v_total
    FROM Area
    WHERE Code_Area = :NEW.Code_Area;
    exception when no_data_found then
       v_total := 1;
    END;
 IF v_total <= 0 THEN
   raise_application_error(990000, 'workers full for this area');
 END IF;
END limit_worker_per_zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a starting point:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LIMIT_WORKER_PER_ZONE
  BEFORE INSERT ON TIMETABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
AS
  nCurrent_workers  NUMBER;
  nMax_workers      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT CURRENT_WORKERS,
         MAX_WORKERS
    INTO nCurrent_workers,
         nMax_workers
    FROM AREA
    WHERE CODE_AREA = :NEW.CODE_AREA;

  IF nCurrent_workers = nMax_workers THEN
    NULL;  -- add code here to do the appropriate thing when the area is already full
  ELSE
    NULL;  -- add code here to to the appropriate thing if the area is not full
  END IF;
END LIMIT_WORKER_PER_ZONE;
```

I'll leave it to you to flesh this out.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You have no exception handling in this at all. Also, you should probably be declaring the variables as `area.current_workers%type;`